# Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I get the following message with this code

```
case when substring(New_Limit,11,1)=' ' then '0'+substring(New_Limit,1,10)
```

The 'then' bit is meant to concat the 0 and substring.
Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that your `New_Limit` variable is a numeric value. You may want to put a `CAST` to (n)varchar around it.

Answer (score 7):

You try to cast it to a string type (varchar) first:

```
SUBSTRING(CAST(New_Limit AS varchar(38)), 11, 1)
```